# Formula to chart reverse S-curve that hits several known points

Tags: math, polynomials

I've been hitting my head against a wall with various formulas for a couple of days, and cannot seem to get one that works for the following points:

```
100,0
35,10
25,37
15,56
10,75
5,90
1,99
0,100
```

Is there a good approach to take to get a curve that connects ALL of these points, without any big jumps (IE - the best formula I have is a polynomial curve that goes very far into the negatives between 35 and 100 on the x.)

I need a smooth gradual curve where all points in between each of these have Y values that are in the same range (IE - from 35 to 100, the curve needs to smoothly go from 10 to 0)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look up cubic interpolation (a series of connected 3rd degree polynomials) or Bezier interpolation for instance.

If you have *n* points, then you *can* include them all with an *n-1* degree polynomial, but you'll run into [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) for any nontrivial input.

You *might* be able to get a smooth curve between 35 and 100 with like a 1000 degree polynomial (by adding lots of intermediate points between the original points) and effectively push Runge's phenomenon outside of your interval.